# Imported Scala Project has no run option

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm taking an online course and was instructed to import a set of exercises into IDEA as a project. I'm unable to run the classes after building and rebuilding the project.
There's a separate getting started course which show's you how to do all of this and it works fine, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

[No option to run the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo4UF.png)

[The getting started project works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGQ2K.png)

I've compared the build.project files and I see errors:
[Errors in the main project for the course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXjRD.png)

I get a message about a problem that I haven't been able to resolve when I run

> sbt sbtVersion

in my project directory:

```
PS M:\School\Scala Applied Part 1> cd .\exercises-applied\
PS M:\School\Scala Applied Part 1\exercises-applied> sbt sbtVersion
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by sbt.TrapExit$ (file:/C:/Users/*/.sbt/boot/scala-2.12.4/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.0/run
_2.12-1.1.0.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of sbt.TrapExit$
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
[info] Loading project definition from M:\School\Scala Applied Part 1\exercises-applied\project
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/Cannot invoke "scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.typerPhase()" because the return value of "scala.tools.nsc.Gl
obal.currentRun()" is null)
```

I can't seem to find

> /modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class

In the file structure and I don't know how to update it.

Comment: 1. From what I see, you imported wrong directory (you should have imported `excercises-applied`) to not have errors in `build.sbt` (it is supposed to be in your root directory and you set `Scala Applied Part 1` as the root), so build isn't found at all. 2. warning is related to having newer JDK and older SBT, newest SBT fix that warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build.sbt needs to bee in the root directory. I've changed the root directory of the project and it builds fine. Thanks Mateusz!